# Forcing Elements in a Numpy Array to be Within a Specified Range

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array and I want to force every element that is less than zero to be zero and every element above 255 will be forced down to 255.

eg. x = (-1,7,255,299)  => (0,7,255,255)

Is there a not too complicated one-liner that can accomplish this?

Comment: Perhaps you should change the title of this question to more accurately reflect your specific problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is numpy.clip

```
numpy.clip(x, 0, 255)
```

Regarding the question posted in your title: don't. You can apply the lambda function to every element, using vectorize but that's rarely the best choice.

Comment: Technically, @senderle answered my question but clip is noticeably faster.

Comment: @Dex, that's because you asked the wrong question.