# numpy convert number to byte

Tags: python, numpy, rounding

I have a numpy matrix with float numbers mostly in range 0-255. However, there are some numbers that are a bit out of range (like -5.36, 270).

I want to convert the matrix to `numpy.uint8` type, so the numbers in range 0-255 can round up or down to the closed int (It doesn't matter), but the numbers are smaller than 0 should be 0, and the numbers are greater than 255 should be 255.

How do you do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forcing Elements in a Numpy Array to be Within a Specified Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035175/forcing-elements-in-a-numpy-array-to-be-within-a-specified-range)

Comment: @ALee. The other question can be deemed a duplicate of this one, but not vice versa. OP is asking for a conversion, not just a clip operation. The first answer posted here is incomplete.

Comment: @ALee. I've gone ahead and hammered the other one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`clip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) will do the first step: clipping to the desired range.

After that, you can use [`ndarray.astype`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) to truncate all the numbers into a `uint8` array:

```
result = np.clip(x, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
```

A better way might be to use `clip`'s `out` parameter to do the truncation all at once. In this case you'll have to explicitly pre-allocate the output buffer:

```
result = np.empty_like(x, dtype=np.uint8)
np.clip(x, 0, 255, out=result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [numpy.clip](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) for that:

```
a = np.arange(10)
np.clip(a, 1, 8)
> array([1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8])
```