# How to obtain minimum between a numpy array and a float number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy array size of `MxN` and a threshold value `T`. A formula is defined as `a_ij = min(a_ij, T)`, for all `a_ij` in array `A_(MxN)`

It means that the threshold `T` will cut the value of the array A in low bound. Do we have any function in python to do it? I used `np.min` but it returned a number instead of an array

For example

```
A =[[1,2],[3,4]]
T=2
A_cut = min(A,T) = [[1,2],[2,2]]
```

Comment: You can use `numpy.clip`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [numpy replace negative values in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335090/numpy-replace-negative-values-in-array) or [Replace all elements of Python NumPy Array that are greater than some value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666626/replace-all-elements-of-python-numpy-array-that-are-greater-than-some-value) or [Forcing Elements in a Numpy Array to be Within a Specified Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035175/forcing-elements-in-a-numpy-array-to-be-within-a-specified-range)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
np.minimum(A, T)
#array([[1,2], [2,2]])
```